# Handle JSP within a java class (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm currently using Spring MVC 4 for developing a new web application.

I have four files named: header.jsp, menu.jsp, default.jsp and footer.jsp, they are basically the template of my webapp.

So, my default.jsp is the default template for every other page in my application, and it's basically like this:

```
...
<jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
<jsp:include page="menu.jsp">
  <body>
    Contents goes here
  </body>
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp">
...
```

The Controller:

```
...
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index() {
   return new ModelAndView("default");
}
...
```

What i want to accomplish is make a java class that can handle header.jsp, one that can handle menu.jsp and so on... Since they will be dynamic pages and their content will change.

I know that i can use java code inside JSP, but that is what i don't wanna do. 
Example of what i would like to do:

```
public class menu {
//this class handles menu.jsp
public List menuItems() {
   ArrayList menuItems = new ArrayList();
    menuItems.add("Home");
    menuItems.add("Contact");
    return menuItems;
}
}
```

And inside menu.jsp:

```
<%@ codebehind="menu.java" %>
<ul>
    <li> ${item[0]} </li> <!-- would output 'Home' -->
    <li> ${item[1]} </li> <!-- would output 'Contact' -->
</ul>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible, you just have to add model on your [ModelAndView](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html).

```
"menuItem" - will be name of your model.
"menu.menuItems()" - is your modelObject.
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index() {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        return new ModelAndView("default", "menuItems", menu.menuItems());
}
```

**Menu**

```
public class Menu {
//this class handles menu.jsp
public List menuItems() {
   ArrayList menuItems = new ArrayList();
    menuItems.add("Home");
    menuItems.add("Contact");
    return menuItems;
}
}
```

Rather than scriptlets, use [jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

```
<%@ codebehind="menu.java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<ul>
       <c:forEach var="menu" value="${menuItem}">
           <li><c:out value="${menu}"/></li>
       </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Also I would recommend you to use [Apache Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/) with [spring](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-mvc-tiles-3-integration) for better template framework.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Maybe i have left some important point, i don't want to use the Controller to handle menu items. I would like to have an independent class to handle menu.jsp. With your solution i would have to make every method return `ModelAndView("default","menuItems",menu.menuItems()))` and this is not what i'm planning to do! Thank you anyway.